# Create Link List

Tags: c++

i just got stocked with this simple prog..
let's take a look:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
int i;
node *nxt;
};



int main()
{

node *head = NULL, *temp = NULL;

head->i = 10;
temp->i = 20;

head->nxt = temp;
temp->nxt = NULL;

cout << head->i << "-" << head->nxt << endl;
cout << temp->i << "-" << temp->nxt << endl;

return 0;
}
```

i really don't know what's the problem!! it give me error with DEV, VS, Code Blocks and... some Runtime and some Compile...

can anyone please answer?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: This `node *head = NULL, *temp = NULL;

head->i = 10;
temp->i = 20;` is undefined behavior.

Comment: so? what should i do if i want to set val of head for 10 and val of temp for 20?

Comment: `node head, temp; head.i = 10; temp.i = 20;`

Comment: yess! it works but i saw a code used -> ... but if i remove * before head and temp i MUST use .

Comment: Nice question and 5 others are better than each other :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write main the following way

```
node node1, node2;

node *head = &node1, *temp = &node2;

head->i = 10;
temp->i = 20;

head->nxt = temp;
temp->nxt = NULL;

cout << head->i << "-" << head->nxt << endl;
cout << temp->i << "-" << temp->nxt << endl;
```

The other approach is to allocate memory dynamically. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct node
{
    int i;
    node *nxt;
};

int main() 
{
    std::unique_ptr<node> head( new node );
    std::unique_ptr<node> temp( new node );

    head->i = 10;
    temp->i = 20;

    head->nxt = temp.get();
    temp->nxt = nullptr;

    std::cout << head->i << "-" << head->nxt << std::endl;
    std::cout << temp->i << "-" << temp->nxt << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
10-0x8745018
20-0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to dereference NULL pointers. You could use `new` like so, to allocate memory for the pointers to point to.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
  int i;
  node *nxt;
};

int main()
{
  node *head = new node, *temp = new node;

  head->i = 10;
  temp->i = 20;

  head->nxt = temp;
  temp->nxt = NULL;

  cout << head->i << "-" << head->nxt << endl;
  cout << temp->i << "-" << temp->nxt << endl;

  delete head;
  delete temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
2 ways for it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
int i;
node *nxt;
};

int main()
{

node head, temp;

head.i=10;
temp.i=20;

head.nxt=&temp;
temp.nxt=NULL;

cout<<head.i<< " - " <<head.nxt<< endl;
cout<<temp.i<< " - " <<temp.nxt<< endl;

return 0;
}
```

**OR**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
int i;
node *nxt;
};

int main()
{

node *head=NULL;
head = new node;

node *temp=NULL;
temp = new node;

head->i=10;
temp->i=20;

head->nxt=temp;
temp->nxt=NULL;

cout<<head->i<< " - " <<head->nxt<< endl;
cout<<temp->i<< " - " <<temp->nxt<< endl;

return 0;
}
```

The difference is the first one use stack for memory and the second one use heap!

Thanks again :)

Comment: If you use `new`, you also should have a corresponding `delete`.

Comment: oh! yes! i added that! tnx :)